# Does in 3D rotations angular velocity about any point can be taken as same as any other point?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

In 3D rotations suppose we have two different angular velocities one for spinning and other for revolution about a point like lets say this figure so here one can see the angular velocity of disc to be along instatenous axis, but lets say we consider any point /axis other than the instaneous axis, will it be same omega (instanenous)  about other point too?

[image]

Comment: The angular velocity appearing in $L_i = I_{ij} \omega_j$ is a vector. Its projection onto different directions are not going to give the same number.

Comment: We say in rigid body angular velocity is same about every points so is it not possible here Sir ? @Connor_Behan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, within a *single rigid body*, all points share the same rotation vector.

Although translational velocity varies from location to location, rotational velocity does not.

As a result, the evaluation of motion on a point **B** if the motion of point **A** both riding on a rigid body is does with the following transformation law

$$\begin{aligned}
 \boldsymbol{\omega}_B &= \boldsymbol{\omega}_A \\
 \boldsymbol{v}_B + \boldsymbol{r}_B \times \boldsymbol{\omega}_B & = \boldsymbol{v}_A + \boldsymbol{r}_A \times \boldsymbol{\omega}_A 
\end{aligned} $$

both the left-hand side and the right-hand side of the above expression correspond to the velocity of the extended rotating frame as measured on the origin. Since it is the same body, this evaluation coming from **A** and coming from **B** must be the same.

[image: fig1]

PS. The rotation axis is defined as the set of points where translational velocity is zero or parallel to the direction of rotation only.

Comment: Sir consider the first example where there is disc rotating and spinning , can u show me if i consider  com of disc and the part which connects it to the O point as the axis of rotation will it be having same w as w at the instatenous axis of rotation , i think this will help me get it understand fully. As its a rigid body so it needs to have that same w isnt ? Just can u prove it Sir ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax - the axis of rotation connects the points that do not move, that is the **O** point and the contact point (not labeled).

Comment: Now i think i got it , yeah sir that is the instaneous axis of rotation , we can take a axis parallel to this one and passing through centre of disc too Sir right rotating with same w ?

Comment: What u say @John_Alexiou Sir , i think we can take any parallel axis and any point on disc which is parallel to IAOR and having same w right ? This was what u meant right Sir ?

Comment: The vector $\omega$ is the same all over as long as the basis vectors do not rotate.

Comment: "Basic vectors" here what you mean Sir?

Comment: [Basis Vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_(linear_algebra)) are the three directions that the vector components represent.

Comment: Hmm understood thanks  Sir